# SharePoint 2007 navigation and removing its delay

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In SharePoint 2007, there's a top nav that the user can hover over, which reveals a dropdown menu of subitems. When they remove their mouse from the dropdown, it disappears, but only after a short delay. This can cause problems, as if people are trying to click a link on the page somewhere, but the nav menu hasn't hidden itself yet, they'll accidentally click it instead. This is compounded with the fact that the menu appearing in the first place is delayed as well, so right before they mouse over the link on the page they *actually* want to click, the menu will suddenly appear and intercept their click when they weren't meaning to.

I've poked at core.js at some suspect areas, but can't seem to nail it down. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour of SharePoint. This control is the asp:Menu control of ASP.Net 2.0 and the only thing you can do is customized the MasterPage or the DefaultPage of your Site.

If you change the core.js file of "layouts" folder you'll lose Microsoft support, so take care about change any of the file from this folder.

I recommend that you modify the existent control or create a new one and put it in this position of the MasterPage.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of CSS will fix it.  I just had the same thing in sharepoint 2010 and this was all that was required to make the list disappear as soon as you roll off:

```
li.hover-off>ul 
{
    display:none;
}
```

The way it works is when you hover over an item in the nav it adds a css class called "hover" and as soon as your mouse leaves the area it changes the class to "hover-off" for 1 second before removing it completely.  This CSS will hide the unordered list directly below the list item that has the class "hover-off" thus hiding the flyout as soon as your mouse leaves the parent.